# Why is there a green border around the annotation?

Tags: tikz-pgf, annotations

I wanted to have a blue annotation to explain one of the points, but it has a green outline, like the color of my mind map. How can I fix that

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}

    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
    \usepackage[a4paper, text={16.5cm, 25.2cm}, centering]{geometry}
    \usepackage[sfdefault]{ClearSans}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \setlength{\parskip}{1.2ex}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0em}

    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{mindmap}

    \begin{document}

    \tikzstyle{every annotation}=[fill=blue!20, text width={}, align=left]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap, grow cyclic,
    every node/.style=concept,concept color=lime!80, level 1/.append style={level distance=5cm, sibling angle=120}, level 2/.append style={level  distance=3 cm, sibling angle=60}]

  \node{Lehramt}
        child{node{Pädagogik}
        child{node{Steop}}
        child{node{Erziehen und Beraten}}
        child{node{Lehren und Lernen}}
        child{node{Schul\-architek\-tur}}
}
child{node{Sport}
    child{node{Physio\-logie}}
    child{node{Anatomie}}
    child{node{Inklusives}}
}
child[level distance=6cm]{node{Französisch}
    child{node{Sprach\-kurs}}
    child{node (n2) {Fach\-didaktik}}
    child{node{Sprach\-wissen\-schaft}} 
    child{node{Landes\-wissen\-schaft}}
    child{node{Medien\-wissen\-schaft}}
    child{node{Literatur\-wissen\-schaft}}
}
;
\node [annotation, right,] at (n2.east) {Französisch unterrichten lernen}
   ;
   \end{tikzpicture}

   \end{document}
```

[image: Mindmap]

Thank you :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Please add an output sample. This isnt necessary but helpful.

Comment: @MaestroGlanz: The example is compilable and as such helpful, which is much more than we get a lot of other times from other users ;-)

Comment: a workaround could be, to set the mindmap color temporary to blue.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Right. But I encountered it sometimes, that it didn't compile or not immediately. And sometimes the mistake can be seen at first sight if we see the output. As I said: Not necessary, but helpful.

Comment: @Katharina: the annotation node {Französisch unterrichten lernen} inherits the settings from the mindmap concept color

Comment: @MaestroGlanz what do you mean with temporary. I set the mind map color to blue. Then my mind map color was blue and the outline of the annotation also. But when I changed the mind map style back to lime, the outline of the annotation was also lime.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer How can I change that.. sry I'm still a beginner..

Comment: Try ` \tikzstyle{every annotation}=[draw=blue!20,fill=blue!20, text width={}, align=left]`

Comment: @Zarko: Isn't `\tikzstyle` outdated?

Comment: @Katharina: Sieht nach Referendariat aus? ;-)

Comment: Yes, it is. I use because that OP more easy to find the necessary change.

Comment: Thank you @Zarko and Christian Hupfer both of your solutions worked … :)

Comment: Please mark a solution, if solved. Btw. for a beginner, this looks pretty nice.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer nein ;) ich hab einfach nur irgendein Thema zum erstellen von einer Mindmaps gesucht...

Comment: @Katharina: :D :D :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `concept color=blue` or `draw=blue` to override the inherited color settings from the mindmap nodes.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, text={16.5cm, 25.2cm}, centering]{geometry}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{ClearSans}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setlength{\parskip}{1.2ex}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap, grow cyclic,
  every node/.style=concept,concept color=lime!80, level 1/.append style={level distance=5cm, sibling angle=120}, level 2/.append style={level  distance=3 cm, sibling angle=60},
  every annotation/.style={concept color=blue,fill=blue!20, text width={}, align=left}%
]
  \node{Lehramt}
  child{node{Pädagogik}
    child{node{Steop}}
    child{node{Erziehen und Beraten}}
    child{node{Lehren und Lernen}}
    child{node{Schul\-architek\-tur}}
  }
  child{node{Sport}
    child{node{Physio\-logie}}
    child{node{Anatomie}}
    child{node{Inklusives}}
  }
  child[level distance=6cm]{node{Französisch}
    child{node{Sprach\-kurs}}
    child{node (n2) {Fach\-didaktik}}
    child{node{Sprach\-wissen\-schaft}} 
    child{node{Landes\-wissen\-schaft}}
    child{node{Medien\-wissen\-schaft}}
    child{node{Literatur\-wissen\-schaft}}
  };
  \node[annotation, right] at (n2.east) {Französisch unterrichten lernen};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I suppose, she wants to have the same blue.

Comment: @MaestroGlanz: I think Katharina is clever enough to change the colour value ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This is no proper solution, but a workaround:

```
\tikzstyle{every annotation}=[fill=blue!20, text width={}, align=left, line width=0.0001pt,]
```

It is not nice, but I dont want to keep it for myself either.